# Overloading operator << in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, pure-virtual

Say I have two classes, one of which is abstract and one of which is a real, derived child of the other. Both of them are overloading the `operator <<` function. How can I call the abstract class' operator from within the derived class' overloaded function?

The set up:

```
class Parent {
    virtual void open() = 0;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Parent& instance);
};

class Derived : public Parent {
    void open();
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Derived& instance);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Derived& instance) {
    out << "derived ";
    out << instance; // how can I call the function in the parent class here?
}
```

I've tried statically casting the instance to the parent class, but you obviously can't because it's an abstract class and cannot be instantiated. `out << static_cast<Parent>(instance);` says "error: a cast to abstract class 'Parent' is not allowed."

I've also tried calling `Parent::operator<<(out, instance)`, but because it's a friend function it is not technically a member function of `Parent`.

So I'm out of ideas... Does anyone know if this can be done? And what the syntax for calling this function is? Cheers.

Comment: You can create a *reference* to the parent class without instantiating it.

Comment: `out << static_cast<const Parent&>(instance);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where you need a type conversion.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Derived& instance)
{
     out << "derived ";
     out << (const Parent &)instance;    // Alternative 1: C style cast
     out << static_cast<const Parent &>(instance);   // Alternative 2
     return out;
}
```

Comment: This was my first idea, but I failed to carefully look at my types. I had previously done `out << static_cast<Parent>(instance)` and it complained. I thought that this was because you cannot instantiate an abstract class, but actually it was because I did the wrong cast. Thank you for forcing me to re-look at the obvious.

Comment: You should never use C-casts in C++!! Definitely not here. An upcast is actually not needed, for downcasting dynamic_cast should be used.

Comment: @DrumM - read the OP's question.   He wants the `operator<<(std::ostream &, const Derived &)` to call `operator<<(std::ostream &, const Parent &)` on the same object.   That means an upcast (implicit or explicit conversion from `Derived &` to `Parent &`) of some form.

Comment: What I mean is, you don't need to cast at all because Parent & Derived are polymorphic.

Comment: The problem asked about is concerned with calling an appropriate overload of an overloaded function.   Polymorphism isn't a solution to that.

Answer (score 7):

There are two approaches to doing this polymorphically:

- Call `<<` of the `Parent` class with an explicit cast, or
- Design a virtual member function into `Parent` to do formatting, and provide a single overload of `<<` for the `Parent`.

Here is the illustration of the second approach:

```
class Parent {
    virtual void open() = 0;
protected:
    virtual std::ostream&  format(std::ostream& out) const {
        out << "hello" << endl;
        return out;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Parent& instance);
};

class Derived : public Parent {
    void open();
    std::ostream&  format(std::ostream& out) const override {
        out << "derived" << endl;
        return Parent::format(out);
    }
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Parent& instance) {
    // Forward the call to a virtual member function
    return instance.format(out);
}
```

Since `format(std::ostream&)` is now a member function, derived classes are free to override it in any way they see fit, or rely on the implementation from the base class.

Comment: The trade-off with the second approach comes when trying to do input.  It will (often) be necessary to work out what type of object was actually output, in order to properly input it.   Which can mean a need to output information that identifies the type.

Comment: @Peter This approach works only for output, not for input. There's no info to direct the flow of execution to a proper member-function until the instance is there, so a type-specific overload should be preferred.